# jQuery slideToggle not working on iPhone

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have a very strange problem. I am working on some navigation for a mobile website. When you click on the link 'Menu', I want the navigation menu to slide down, and then closed when 'Menu' is clicked again.

Here is a link to a codepen...

http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/EaKtb

As you can see the jQuery code I am using is this...

```
$('.menuNav').click(function(){
    $('#menu-primary-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

This codepen is the code taken from my actual site.

The navigation dropdown on my actual site works in all browsers, and even on an IOS simulator, however it does not work on my iPhone, even though this codepen does.

When you click on the Menu, nothing happens.

I am not sure why this is or how to debug. I have removed all other JS but still does not work.

I find it strange that this codepen demo works on my iPhone but the actual code (which is the same) does not work. I am using jQuery version 1.9.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Codepen works fine on iPhone (as you said). What other scripts are on your page?

Comment: The actual code is with wordpress. I have disabled all other scripts. I have tried changing the .menuNav into an anchor link. I am not sure what else it could be.

Comment: Do you know that wordpress runs jQuery in [`noConflict`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) mode? Try wrapping your jQuery code in: `(function($) {
    /* your code here */
})(jQuery);`

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I found out what the issue was

Answer (score 0):

I think that issue comes from CSS, not jQuery.

Try cleaning up your CSS, and the issue might disappear.

For example:

- all transitions on the menu are useless as you're using jQuery to animate it.
- `float: left` on menu items is unnecessary.

You can check also check how the menu or its container is positioned on your website (absolute, fixed...). There are some issues with positioning on iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I have founded the answer. It turns out everything was correct, just my js file was not being updated on mobile.

I found this out by using the new web inspector feature on IOS6 and inspected the files. I then cleared my iPhone cache and is now working.